# How to add/align Label to Semantic UI DropDown control

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

This should be simple, but I can't find an easy solution. I simply want to have a label of "State" next to my DropDown State selection to appear like it does with the  Control where you specify a Label.

Is there a way to do this?

I've tried using  but it doesn't work when I set the fluid attribute of the dropdown.

```
              <Grid.Row>   
                <Grid.Column width={8} >
                <Form.Field inline>
                <Input width="600px" fluid readOnly={checkInputActive(city)} label="City"  name="city" placeholder="Enter your City" value={city}  onChange={onCityChange} />
                </Form.Field>
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column verticalAlign="middle">
                   <Icon size="big" color="green" name="edit outline" />
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Row>   
                <Grid.Column width={8} >
        <Form.Field inline>
       <Label>State</Label>
        <Dropdown labeled value={stateLocation} label="State" fluid inline search options={stateOptions} selection placeholder="Select your State" />
        </Form.Field>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column verticalAlign="middle">
        <Icon name="edit outline" />
        </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
```

See the screenshot of this looks. I just want the label to appear as it does with the City input field:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The dropdown component doesn't support labels currently but you can still achieve the same effect using this

```
<Input
  label="Country"
  fluid
  input={
    <Dropdown
      placeholder="Select Country"
      fluid
      search
      selection
      options={countryOptions}
      style={{
        borderRadius: "0 4px 4px 0"
      }}
    />
  }
/>
```

You need to set the border radius manually since it doesn't attach to the label because its currently unsupported.

https://codesandbox.io/s/6yk4k02myr?module=%2Fexample.js